# Text formatting while display

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller, formatting

I am developing a portal where I need to fetch the code from backend and display that in view. I am able to fetch the code from backend and using below code part to display the details in view

```
@model Dictionary<System.String,System.String>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Code";
}
<br />
<p>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3 class="panel-title">@Html.DisplayFor(val => item.Key)</h3>
                <text class="panel-body">@Html.DisplayFor(val => item.Value)   </text>
              </div>
        </div>
    }
</p>
```

So the controller is returning a dictionary object which has code title(item.key in above code) and code snippet(item.value in above code) which I am trying to display, but there is no indentation or formatting in the code part when it is getting displayed in UI. I need to do formatting while display. Is there any way that this can be done

Comment: What does "but there is no indentation or formatting in the code part" mean specifically? Do you want to indent the HTML code tags? Or if you want to indent the text in the HTML page, what container are you referencing to indicate they are indented/not indented?

Answer (score 0):

This was silly, there is tag called `<pre>` which renders the data as it is stored in the backend, just figured out.